# Sql query on PHP problems?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Its hard to explain my problem and what I want to do, but if you read my code you will understand.

When I log in, I have `$username` as cookie and I call it on this page, and it work. Like this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) 
{ 
    $username = $_COOKIE['username']; 
} 
?>
```

Now I want to get the id of this `$username`, form the table `users`. So this is my query:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
?>
```

And then I have this next query, where I'm trying to get results where `$username id = schedules.id_doc` which is a foreign key of the table `users`.

```
<?php 
$doc = "SELECT users.emri, users.mbiemri, schedules.visit_date, schedules.visit_time\n" 
    . "FROM schedules\n" 
    . "INNER JOIN users"; 
    . "WHERE schedules.id_doc = '$result2'"; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $doc); 
?>
```

So this doesn't work and when I debug it it says that the problem is at 
`. "WHERE schedules.id_doc = '$result2'";`

I'm not sure if i can do this on this way, or it have another way.

Comment: remove the "\n" in your string. "\n" isn't sql command or available in syntax.

Comment: yes but it works like this

Comment: You've forgotten to put an ON clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an alias of your table and you've forgot the `ON` clause. Your query should be like this:

```
$doc = "SELECT users.emri, users.mbiemri, schedules.visit_date,     
        schedules.visit_time\n" 
       . "FROM schedules A \n" 
       . "INNER JOIN users B ON A.id_doc=B.id" 
       . "WHERE A.id_doc = '$result2'";
```

Or put it in one line code. See below:

```
$doc = "SELECT users.emri, users.mbiemri, schedules.visit_date, schedules.visit_time FROM schedules A INNER JOIN users B ON A.id_doc=B.id WHERE A.id_doc = '$result2'";
```

Comment: Your code have a wrong `;` on the `INNER JOIN` line.

Comment: i try doesn't work. when i put WHERE under // it works but it fetch all data not only of those of the user that i want

Comment: Try putting your code in one line and identify if your query or coding has the error.

Comment: it keep showing the error on '. "WHERE A.id_doc = '$result2'";  '

Comment: I just try it still nothing :(

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong in your query. Try running your query in your MySQL. Replace $result2 with specific doc_id for checking.

Comment: something like this? 
`SELECT users.emri, users.mbiemri, schedules.visit_date, schedules.visit_time 
FROM schedules A
INNER JOIN users B ON A.id_doc=B.id
WHERE A.id_doc = '2'`

Comment: Yes. If your query works in MySQL, then there is something wrong with your PHP code.

Comment: wow its not working so it looks like my problem is on my database right?

Comment: Absolutely, try revising your query first. Make it work in MySQL before putting it in your PHP codes.

Comment: My friend one more question. now it show me problem with cookie, when i try to echo it writes only ROOT. do u have any idea about this?

Comment: sorry i found the problem )

Answer (score 2):

You have a `;` in the line `. "INNER JOIN users";`.

If you remove the `;` your code will work.

Also you don't need the `\n` at the end of the lines.